# Sentiment retriving from text (Russian)

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

Does anybody knows python library to retrieve sentiment from Russian text. The dictionary with sentiment parameterization will be ok to. The idea of library something like in GPOMS in [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.3003).

Comment: Why should it be any different from, say, English? Python can transparently process UTF8. Do you foresee any specific problem with grammar or anything?

Comment: @Diego, as I understand, I need a dictionary of words of the Russian language with the weight of each word (something like [this](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=6010) for English). Which library could you advise my?

Comment: May be you should replace the word library with the word dictionary in your question. Python library is usually referring to a bunch of functions and classes, not just a collection of words.

Comment: @Diego, thank you for recommendation, but I think my question correctly shows that I'm 
interested in dictionary or library. Both for me will be ok.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6691/sentiment-analysis-model-for-spanish

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sentiment Analysis model for Spanish](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6691/sentiment-analysis-model-for-spanish)

Comment: Have a question for polyglot solution. Because Russian language was not set explicitly, how do you know that the word polarity is correct for Russian and not for English which I assume is the default language used by polyglot sentiment module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are seeking a working solution, I know of an API that supports many languages, including Russian: [indico.io Text Analysis sentiment()](https://indico.io/docs#sentiment)

```
>>> import indicoio
>>> indicoio.config.api_key = YOUR_API_KEY
>>> indicoio.sentiment(u"Это круто, убивает!  Хочу.", language='ru')
0.6978093435482927
>>> indicoio.sentiment(u"Ты кто такой?  Давай досвидания", language='ru')
0.13258737684773209
```

Note that the `language` parameter is optional

(Obviously it's not a lib, but they offer a Python client and their free tier is generous enough.)

Update: As of Q2 2018, Google and IBM sentiment analysis APIs still do not support Russian.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the [polyglot](http://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Sentiment.html) library. It has polarity lexicons for 136 languages, including Russian.

> The scale of the words’ polarity consisted of three degrees: +1 for
>   positive words, and -1 for negatives words. Neutral words will have a
>   score of 0.

You can use it like this:

```
>>> from polyglot.text import Text as T
>>> text = T("это очень плохо. А это намного лучше, даже хорошо!")
>>> text.polarity
0.33333333333333331

>>> for s in text.sentences:
...  s, s.polarity
... 
(Sentence("это очень плохо."), -1.0)
(Sentence("А это намного лучше, даже хорошо!"), 1.0)

>>> for w in text.words:
...   print("{:<16}{:>2}".format(w, w.polarity))
... 
это              0
очень            0
плохо           -1
.                0
А                0
это              0
намного          0
лучше            1
,                0
даже             0
хорошо           1
!                0
```